# Looking for advice on JavaScript RSA encryption

Tags: javascript, rsa, encryption

I have a need to encrypt data entered by users on a form on the client side. My environment doesn't have ssl encryption, but I have found out that in my case I can achieve a similar result with RSA encryption. The public key will be used on the client side, and the owner of the private key will later be able to retrieve and decrypt the data.

Before I go down that route, I'd like to make sure I haven't overlooked any key issue. So here are a few questions:

- can you recommend JavaScript libraries that do RSA encryption?
- what guarantees that they are reliable?
- what are the shortcomings of this technique? For example a lost message if the user closes the browser too fast?

Generally speaking, I'd be interested in any advice on this JavaScript RSA encryption technique.

Update: the only RSA JavaScript I have found so far is on this page:
http://www.ohdave.com/rsa/
Any feedback on that one?

Also, I am ok with encryption other than RSA, if you have any to recommend. My constraint is to have a 100% JavaScript solution.

Comment: While you can do that, it's not much more secure than an unencrypted connection. An attacker can simply modify the JS the client receives and use that to intercept the secret stuff. Trusting only certain certificates is a core feature of SSL, and you can't emulate that with JS.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I understand, but as I said in the question it works in my case. I am ok with the message being intercepted, not ok with the content being read.

Comment: I don't really understand why you think it works for you. Once the attacker has control over your js he can simply remove the encryption and read the now unencrypted content. A MITM can read and manipulate everything in your scenario. You just block passive listeners.

Comment: It works for me because encryption and decryption are done in secure environments where I use js. Only the encrypted message goes over the internet.

Comment: So your program is a client application written in js and not a website containing your program. So the source of your js is trusted. Yes, in that case it should work.

Answer (score 4):

This is possible, however it should be pointed out that this is in no way a replacement for TLS - largely because techniques like this offer no enforceable trust or authentication between the client and server; your script can't verify the the public key embedded within it is *your* public key, anyone who can get in between you & your client could substitute their own.

Comment: Would you have a pure JavaScript one to recommend?

Comment: jcryption is the only one I know of, if you search SO for it you may get some other links

Comment: @AlexK, the keys can be substituted but once you do that your message is not readable by recipient.

Answer (score 1):

https://sourceforge.net/projects/pidcrypt/ seems to be gaining popularity. I am evaluating it to be used in our project. Will post update if I managed to use this library.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look to [asmcrypto.js](https://github.com/vibornoff/asmcrypto.js) — there is a lot of crypto algorithms implemented including RSA and it's [really](http://jsperf.com/jsbn-vs-bigint-js-modular-exponentiation-montgomery/4) [damn](http://jsperf.com/aes) [fast](http://jsperf.com/pbkdf2-hmac-sha256/2).

BTW I'm an author and would be glad to get some feedback and answer your questions if any.

Answer (score 1):

If your javascript environment is secure (eg. https) and you do not have a requirement to support old browser versions **Subtle.Crypto** can be used to create a good security model. You will need to understand well what you are doing and how the encryption, signing, key storage, etc will be achieved in your environment. *There are many pitfalls to rolling your own.*

A good place to start is to consider if you need to distribute individual AES keys for rapid and secure encryption. If so then you may want to use RSA to encrypt and transmit individual AES keys and then use AES for the bulk of your encryption. Keep signing in mind. In many cases simply signing a payload so that it can be verified as intact is enough. It may be unnecessary to hide your data at rest or in transit.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto

Answer (score 0):

Plain lightweight javascript library crypto4js has implemented RSA encryption. You can use it https://github.com/atul19971/crypto4js .